# pod lock file not generating all the dependencies are downloading in flutter

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, flutter-ios

**getting this error while pod install**

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `=~' for [["PICKER_MEDIA=1"], ["PICKER_AUDIO=1"], ["PICKER_DOCUMENT=1"]]:Array
```

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:446:in `block (2 levels) in merged_xcconfigs' /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:446:in` all?'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:446:in `block in merged_xcconfigs' /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:444:in` each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:444:in `each_with_object' /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:444:in` merged_xcconfigs'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:1057:in `block in <class:PodTargetSettings>' /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:120:in` block in define_build_settings_method'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:177:in `block in remove_pod_target_xcconfig_overrides_from_target' /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:174:in` each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:174:in `remove_pod_target_xcconfig_overrides_from_target' /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:157:in` block in add_target'
internal:kernel:90:in `tap' /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:156:in` add_target'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:47:in `block in install!' /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:149:in` message'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:40:in `install!' /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:115:in` block in install_pod_targets'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:112:in `map' /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:112:in` install_pod_targets'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/single_pods_project_generator.rb:32:in `block in install_all_pod_targets' /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:149:in` message'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/single_pods_project_generator.rb:31:in `install_all_pod_targets' /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/single_pods_project_generator.rb:19:in` generate!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:314:in `block in create_and_save_projects' /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in` section'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:309:in `create_and_save_projects' /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:301:in` generate_pods_project'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:180:in `integrate' /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:167:in` install!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/update.rb:63:in `run' /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in` run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run' /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in` <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:25:in `load' /usr/local/bin/pod:25:in` '

Comment: Try running `brew reinstall cocoapods`, then go in your project, `flutter clean` and run the app through Android Studio as you would usuallly do.

Comment: this is not the solution please check my answer for the reference

Comment: Well your solution involves directly modifying the build settings config, it’s probably safer to reinstall cocoapods but if your solution worked then godspeed spiderman.

Comment: i tried to reinstall cocoapods but it didn't worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this it'll solve the issue**

```
I got the same issue in this file gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:446:in `block (2 levels) in merged_xcconfigs' installing with gem
ruby 3.2.0
replacing "=~" by "==" seems to work but no idea if it has side effects I am just using this thing
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Replace `=~` with `==` in the file: `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb`

line: 446 -

```
after modification: values_are_bools = uniq_values.all? { |v| v == /\A(yes|no)\z/i }
```

It will work.

Ref: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11720#issuecomment-1378240043

Comment: This solved it for me too, my path was: vim ~/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb